# Date with conversion function gives error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

While i execute below query

```
SELECT (TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR ('25-07-19', 'YYYY')) - 1) + CEIL
(
  CASE
  WHEN (MONTHS_BETWEEN ( LAST_DAY ( TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR ('18-05-2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')), LAST_DAY ('25-07-19')))>0 THEN
  MONTHS_BETWEEN ( LAST_DAY ( TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR ('18-05-2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')), LAST_DAY ('25-07-19'))
  ELSE 1 END / 12) Year 
  FROM dual;
```

Am getting returns error as below

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Comment: Why `TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR ('25-07-19', 'YYYY')) - 1` instead of simply writing `2018`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain the purpose of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from calling `TO_CHAR`, such as:

```sql
TO_CHAR ('25-07-19', 'YYYY')
```

or

```sql
TO_CHAR ('18-05-2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

The `TO_CHAR` function is overloaded and the first argument can either be a number or a date; you have supplied neither and passed in a string so Oracle is attempting to implicitly convert `'25-07-19'` and `'18-05-2020'` to numbers, since it does not know that you want it to be a date. You should not rely on implicit conversions.

Instead you could explicitly convert your string to a date:

```sql
TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE( '18-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

But, better would be to use a date literal `DATE '2020-05-18'` or, if you are immediately going to convert it to a string again then just supply the string in the correct format.

So, you can simplify your function a lot by eliminating the `TO_CHAR` calls and replacing most of `TO_DATE` calls with date literals. Similarly, you don't need to use `TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( date_value, 'YYYY' ) )` and can instead use `EXTRACT`. You can also replace your `CASE` statement with `GREATEST`.

Which gets you to a much simpler query:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM DATE '2019-07-25' )
       - 1
       + CEIL(
           GREATEST(
             MONTHS_BETWEEN(
               LAST_DAY( DATE '2020-05-18' ),
               LAST_DAY( DATE '2019-07-25' )
             ),
             1
           ) / 12
         ) AS Year
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | YEAR |
> | ---: |
> | 2019 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a66347fcb996881ce036ec4e85320982)*

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string values with date to a date datatype first, using [`TO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm):

```
SELECT (TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE('25-07-19', 'DD-MM-YY'), 'YYYY')) - 1) + CEIL
(
  CASE WHEN (
    MONTHS_BETWEEN(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('18-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')), LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('25-07-19', 'DD-MM-YY')))) > 0 THEN
      MONTHS_BETWEEN(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('18-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')), LAST_DAY (TO_DATE('25-07-19', 'DD-MM-YY')))
  ELSE 1 END / 12) Year 
  FROM dual;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=141f065818f7b94531fad04db452df8e)

Comment: By keeping 2-digit years, you just recreated the Y2K bug, and taught the OP to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('25-07-19', 'DD-MM-YY'), 'YYYY')) - 1) + 
  CEIL (
      CASE
          WHEN (MONTHS_BETWEEN(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('18-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')), LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('25-07-19','DD-MM-YY')))) > 0 THEN 
                MONTHS_BETWEEN(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('18-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')), LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('25-07-19','DD-MM-YY')))
          ELSE 1
      END / 12) YEAR
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Removed TO_CHAR from MONTHS_BETWEEN, as it is not required